# VMWare Fusion and moving between monitors

Tags: display, vmware

I'm running a Windows 2012 guest in VMWare Fusion 8.5.6 on my Macbook pro.

The VM itself is fine but the problem is: at work, my secondary display is a high-density Samsung, where I need things scaled up in the guest to be able to see them, but at home I use a standard-density Acer, where (at 200%) the text is enormous.

Is there a way for Fusion to auto-scale the guest based on the attached monitor?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Autofit command of view menu you can resize the guest display resolution. There are four commands listed below:

1. **Fit Guest Now -** Guest operating system display size to match current Workstation console.
2. **Fit Window Now -** The Workstation console to match the current display size of the guest operating system.
3. **Autofit Window -** Workstation console to maintain the size of the virtual machine's display resolution.
4. **Autofit Guest -** Virtual machine to resize the guest display resolution to match the size of the Workstation console.

As per your requirement, Fit Guest Now command will remain the best.

You should also refer this: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_display_fitting_host.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.